# I have used following query getting error

Tags: php, mysql

I have used following query..

```
$query1= mysql_query("INSERT into pg(pgmail, pgpass, pgfname, pgmname, pglname, updt, dtcreate) values('$email','$pass', '$fname', '$mname', '$lname', now(), mktime())")or die(mysql_error());
```

ERROR : **FUNCTION mydb.mktime does not exist**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
...'$mname', '$lname', now(), '".mktime()."')")or die(...
```

since `now()` is a valid MYSQL function, but `mktime()` is a php function, which is not evaluated in string context.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to utilise the php mktime() function, you've enclosed the function call in the DB string, so the DB is attempting to call the function (which doesn't exist to the DB).

Simply remove the function call from the string body.

Answer (score 0):

Try NOW(), there is no mktime function in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

There are no `mktime` mysql function
If you want to use PHP `mktime()` you should not qoute it

```
$query1= mysql_query("INSERT into pg(pgmail, pgpass, pgfname, pgmname, pglname, updt, dtcreate) values('$email','$pass', '$fname', '$mname', '$lname', now(), ".mktime().")")or die(mysql_error());
```

Besides, use `time()` instead of `mktime()` without parametrs

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1= mysql_query("INSERT into pg(pgmail, pgpass, pgfname, pgmname, pglname, updt, dtcreate) values('$email','$pass', '$fname', '$mname', '$lname', now(), " . mktime() . ")")or die(mysql_error());
```